# How do I represent a grid with few thick edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bold, grids

[image]

How do I represent the following image in `LaTeX`? I could have done it using `\tikzpicture`, however I wish to have few bold edges as described in the image (grid corresponding to time step `k+1`). I am not sure if that can be done using `\tikzpicture`. Let me know how I can do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need a hammersledge like TiKZ to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant with `array` and `boldline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{boldline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\rule[-1mm]{0pt}{9mm}}m{5mm}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}}
\hline
 & & \\
 \hline\clineB{2-2}{3}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c V{3}}{A} & X \\
\hline
 & X & \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{>{\rule{0pt}{5mm}}c}{Time Step = k}
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!It worked.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible solutions using a regular `tabular` in combination with the `boldline` package or using a `tikz` `matrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    & x                          &    \\ 
  \hline \clineB{2-2}{2}
  x & \multicolumn{1}{V{2}c|}{x} & x  \\ 
  \hline
    & x                          &    \\ 
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{text}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center,
         minimum width=0.5cm,
         minimum height=0.5cm, 
         fill=none, 
         draw=black},
  row 4/.style = {nodes={minimum height=0.75cm,
                         fill=none, 
                         draw=none}},
  ] 
  {
      & x &    \\
    x & x & x  \\
      & x &    \\
      &   &    \\
  };
  \node[fit=(table-4-1)(table-4-3)]{text};
  \draw [black, very  thick] (table-2-2.north east) -- (table-2-2.north west) -- (table-2-2.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: @SivaJagadesh The TikZ solution is very be easy to transform in an environment and some macros with a simple API.